# DeltaTable schema not updating when using `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMNS`

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm currently playing with [Delta Tables](https://docs.delta.io/latest/index.html) on my local machine and I encountered a behavior that I don't understand.
I create my DeltaTable like so:

```py
df.write \
    .format('delta') \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .option('overwriteSchema', 'true') \
    .save(my_table_path)

dt = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, my_table_path)
```

Then, I run the following command.

```py
spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE delta.`{my_table_path}` ADD COLUMNS (my_new_col string)")
```

This adds a new column to the schema as can be seen by running

```py
spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE delta.`{my_table_path}`").show()
```

It even shows as the last DeltaTable operation in the history, by running `dt.history().show()`.

However, this is not reflected in the DeltaTable object `dt`, infact if I run `dt.toDF().printSchema()`, the new column is not displayed.

On the other hand, if I do something like

```py
spark.sql(f"UPDATE delta.`{my_table_path}` SET existing_col = 'foo'")
```

and after I run `dt.toDF().show()`, the update is reflected and shown under `existing_col`, which now appears containing `foo` everywhere.

The only way I found out to have the `dt` object reflect the schema change, is to run `dt = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, my_table_path)` again after `ALTER TABLE`.

What am I missing?

---

**Edit**: Added repo link for reproducibility.

https://github.com/wtfzambo/delta-bug-working-example

**Edit2**: Repo uses Delta 1.0, but issue exists also in Delta 2.*

Comment: Could you provide a working example for this so we can recreate the issue?  Thanks!

Comment: What is the Delta package version?

Comment: @DennyLee there you go, I added a small repo to the bottom that should allow you to reproduce  the bug. Cheers!

Comment: @AlexOtt version 1.0.0. I made a small repo to reproduce the bug, it's linked at the bottom of the question

Comment: Oh thanks @wtfzambo - sorry for missing this!  Out of curiosity, were you able to repro this in a more recent version of Delta (e.g. Delta 2.0, 2.1, or 2.2)?

Comment: @DennyLee admittedly I haven't tried. I was using 1.0.0 because I run certain AWS Glue jobs using Glue V.3, and that doesn't support Delta 2.*. At the time, Glue V.4 didn't exist yet. I will try with Delta 2.* and see what happens

Comment: @DennyLee hey there, sorry for the late update. I confirm that the issue persists when using Delta 2.*

Comment: Thanks @wtfzambo - will work on reproing it - thanks for doing this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your patience @wtfzambo - I just realized when I reproed this myself I should seen the issue immediately so sorry for taking so long to realize this.   Actually, the way this works is as expected but allow me to explain.

- When you ran the `ALTER TABLE` statement, the schema in fact did change and it was registered within the Delta transaction log but up to this point, it was a metadata change.
- Once you ran the `UPDATE` statement, then this was registered and the data itself reflected this change, i.e. the Parquet files within the table can see this change.
- When you ran the `dt.toDF().printSchema()`, it is because the DataFrame could only see the data and metadata together but when you ran the `ALTER TABLE` statement, it was only a metadata change.

To better showcase this, allow me to provide context via the file system. To recreate this exact scenario, please use the docker at https://go.delta.io/docker and use the `DELTA_PACKAGE_VERSION` as `delta-core_2.12:2.1.0`.  That is, run the Docker container and use the pts-ark steps:

1. To start PySpark, run the command:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --packages io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.1.0 \
--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" \
--conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"
```

2. Run the basic commands to create a simple table

```
# Create Spark DataFrame
data = spark.range(0, 5)

# Write Delta table
data.write.format("delta").save("/tmp/delta-table")

# Read Delta table
df = spark.read.format("delta").load("/tmp/delta-table")

# Show Delta table
df.show()
```

3. When you run the command `spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE delta.'/tmp/delta-table/'").show()`, you will see:

```
+---------------+---------+-------+
|       col_name|data_type|comment|
+---------------+---------+-------+
|             id|   bigint|       |
|               |         |       |
| # Partitioning|         |       |
|Not partitioned|         |       |
+---------------+---------+-------+
```

As well, if you list the files of the table:

```
NBuser@5b0edf0b8779:/tmp/delta-table$ ls -lsgA
total 44
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 NBuser 4096 Mar 12 23:50 _delta_log
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser  478 Mar 12 23:29 part-00000-4abcc1fa-b2c8-441a-a392-8dab57edd819-c000.snappy.parquet
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser   12 Mar 12 23:29 .part-00000-4abcc1fa-b2c8-441a-a392-8dab57edd819-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser  478 Mar 12 23:29 part-00001-6327358c-8c00-4ad6-9e3d-263f0ea66e3f-c000.snappy.parquet
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser   12 Mar 12 23:29 .part-00001-6327358c-8c00-4ad6-9e3d-263f0ea66e3f-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser  478 Mar 12 23:29 part-00002-eea1d287-be68-4a62-874d-ab4e39c6a825-c000.snappy.parquet
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser   12 Mar 12 23:29 .part-00002-eea1d287-be68-4a62-874d-ab4e39c6a825-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser  478 Mar 12 23:29 part-00003-c79b4180-5968-4fee-8181-6752d9cfb333-c000.snappy.parquet
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser   12 Mar 12 23:29 .part-00003-c79b4180-5968-4fee-8181-6752d9cfb333-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser  478 Mar 12 23:29 part-00004-c3399acd-75ca-4ea5-85f9-03fa60897161-c000.snappy.parquet
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser   12 Mar 12 23:29 .part-00004-c3399acd-75ca-4ea5-85f9-03fa60897161-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
```

4. Now, let's run the ALTER command ala `spark.sql(f"ALTER TABLE delta.'/tmp/delta-table/' ADD COLUMNS (blah string)")` and when you run the `DESCRIBE TABLE` statement, you get what you expected:

```
spark.sql(f"DESCRIBE TABLE delta.`/tmp/delta-table/`").show()

+---------------+---------+-------+
|       col_name|data_type|comment|
+---------------+---------+-------+
|             id|   bigint|       |
|           blah|   string|       |
|               |         |       |
| # Partitioning|         |       |
|Not partitioned|         |       |
+---------------+---------+-------+
```

But, if you were to run the `ls -lsgA` for the temp table, note that the files look *exactly the same*.  That is, there are no changes to the data, but only the metadata.

To see this, run the command:

```
NBuser@5b0edf0b8779:/tmp/delta-table/_delta_log$ ls -lsgA
total 16
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser 2082 Mar 12 23:29 00000000000000000000.json
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser   28 Mar 12 23:29 .00000000000000000000.json.crc
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser  752 Mar 12 23:38 00000000000000000001.json
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 NBuser   16 Mar 12 23:38 .00000000000000000001.json.crc
```

Note the `00000000000000000001.json` which contains the transaction which corresponds to your `ALTER TABLE` command.  If you were to read this `.json` file it would like this:

```
{"metaData": {
    "id":"d583238c-87ab-4de0-a09d-141ef499371d",
    "format":{"provider":"parquet","options":{}},
    "schemaString":"
        {\"type\":\"struct\",
         \"fields\":[{\"name\":\"id\",\"type\":\"long\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}},
                     {\"name\":\"blah\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}]}"
                     ,"partitionColumns":[],"configuration":{},"createdTime":1678663791967}}
    {"commitInfo":{"timestamp":1678664321014,
        "operation":"ADD COLUMNS","operationParameters":{"columns":"[{\"column\":{\"name\":\"blah\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}}]"},"readVersion":0,"isolationLevel":"Serializable","isBlindAppend":true,"operationMetrics":{},"engineInfo":"Apache-Spark/3.3.1 Delta-Lake/2.1.0","txnId":"b54db68d-652b-4930-82d5-61a542d82100"}}
```

Notice the schemaString -> fields which show the `blah` column and notice the `operation` command that points to a `ADD COLUMNS` command which also includes the `blah` column.

> So the key point here is that while the transaction log contains the `blah` column being added, the root table directory table folder has no changes to the .parquet files meaning that the change was reflected in the metadata but not the data.

Until you ran the `UPDATE` command, the changes were not reflected in the .parquet files (i.e. data files).  And in the case of the Spark DataFrame, it can only pull the schema when it's associated with the data.

Comment: This makes so much sense Denny, thanks for taking the time to explain it to me 

Comment: Glad to help - and thanks for your patience, eh?! :)